# SQLite3 Python Library returning database location not contents, despite fetchall()

Tags: python, sqlite

so I am working on a project in which I am displaying HTML cards based on the number of 'Events' as in, physical events (irrelevant, just for a bit of context).
Here is my code:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

connection = sqlite3.connect("./app/database.db", check_same_thread=False)
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

@app.route('/')
def index():

    
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    events = cursor.execute("SELECT name, date, time, venue FROM events").fetchall()
    
    print(events)
        

    return render_template("index.html", events=events)
```

However the content of events then becomes a list of `<sqlite3.Row object at 0x1071544f0>`s

You will notice that I **have** done the .fetchall() correctly.

**NOTE:** The intended behaviour is achieved if I remove `connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` but then the format is not what I want. I need the output to be a list[] of dictionaries{} and without that line, the output is a list[] of strings containing parenthesis (If I've understood?)

Can someone shed some light?

I am used to CS50 (Harvard's course)'s SQL library which is very similar but simplified for learning, in which all you have to do is db=database and then db.execute("")

Thank you guys!

Comment: Of course it is a list of sqlite3.Row objects, that's **exactly** what `connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` does. That isn't the "locations". That is just the default representation of an object inherited from `object.__repr__`, the information is in there.

Comment: Oh! For some reason I thought that connection.row_factory=sqlite3.Row would convert the rows into dictionaries. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: Note, if you actually need dictionaries, the [docs provide an example that does just that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory)

Comment: And note, you can just use `dict(row)` on row objects to convert them to dicts... they are already "dict-like", (implement `.keys()` and `__getitem__`)